# Intellij not finding packages

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, gatling, intellij-15

I'm trying to integrate `Gatling` into my project and I've got [this example working](https://github.com/satyriasizz/gatling2-load-test-example), but again, I'd like to pull it into an existing project.

I'm attempting to create a new directory within my project structure to house the `Gatling` stuff, but any `.scala` file I put in there doesn't seem to find my packages upon import (see image: works and doesnt work areas)

[image: works_doesntWork]

I'm not seeing any errors in my Intellij build.sbt/plugins.sbt files, which is obvious if one of the `.scala` files is seeing the packages. I'm totally lost with this problem.

By "not seeing my packages" I mean, when I `import io.gatling...` works.scala finds the packages whereas doesntWork.scala doesn't seem to see anything (not just `io.gatling`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is more related to your overall build. [Gatling expects](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/extensions/sbt_plugin.html#default-settings) your simulation classes to be in `src/test/scala` directory, but you can change its expectations. Just add the following setting into your `build.sbt`:

```
scalaSource in Gatling := file("qa")
```

This will solve your problem in `sbt` layer. You can prove it via running the `sbt ' in console and typing:

```
inspect gatling:scalaSource
```

or simply

```
galting:test
```

Another side of your problem is Intellij. I'm not sure if you have imported the whole project via Intellij sbt import or not. but I'm guessing that scala sbt plugin is not such a smart to recognize your specific changes to sources. You can 
prove this by reimporting the whole project or just clicking refresh in your SBT tool window:

[image: SBT tool window]

To open the tool window select **View > Tool Windows > SBT** from menu.

If it does not help (and I assume it won't) you can still add the `qa` directory into test directories. Just select **File > Project Structure** from menu. Select **Modules** in the left pane. Select your project in middle pane. Select **Sources** tab, your directory and click **Tests** in the **Mark as** row. Commit your changes with **OK** button. See picture bellow:

[image]

Now your Intellij should compile your simulations.

Btw: files in `project` directory are considered as separate module in IntelliJ, hence they compile. Same structure and point of view has also SBT, which considers 
everything under this directory to be separate module. That explains why your files there compile.

Enjoy